# How to create a pending changelist using Perforce Fusion

Tags: perforce

I want to switch to Perforce Fusion to use git with Perforce. As I understand, whenever I push a commit it creates a submitted changelist on the Perforce server. Is there any way to create pending changelist from git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git Fusion stick's to Git's all or nothing approach when dealing with pushes.

Either all of the commits that make up a push make it in to the Helix Server (P4D) or none of them do.

It therefore does not provide an option to store Git Commits in pending changelists, because then the chance of commits that make up a push being split up or becoming out of order would be greatly increased.

Hope this helps,
Jen.

Comment: thanks, that's so unfortunate. We have code reviews and build validation before the submit based on pending changelist. I think in such case there is no use for git fusion in our case